# How do I set the index to a grouped value in pandas?

Tags: python, indexing, group-by

I have tried to follow examples on here to what I think should work.  I would like to get all the data grouped by `'Continent'` and then set that as my index.  I have tried to group the data:

```
cont.head()
```

```
    Country Continent   Population
0   China   Asia    1367.645161
1   United States   North America   317.615385
2   Japan   Asia    127.409396
3   United Kingdom  Europe  63.870968
4   Russian Federation  Europe  143.500000
```

```
cont = cont.groupby('Continent')
cont
```

But I keep getting this result instead of the actual grouped dataframe.

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f7ab3ae6ee0>
```

##Edit
I have iterated over the columns with calculations and this is my final DataFrame, however I would like each continent to be listed only once in the index

```
        Country Population  sum size    mean    std
Continent                       
Asia    China   1367.645161 2898.666387 5   579.733277  679.097888
Asia    Japan   127.409396  2898.666387 5   579.733277  679.097888
Asia    India   1276.730769 2898.666387 5   579.733277  679.097888
Asia    South Korea 49.805430   2898.666387 5   579.733277  679.097888
Asia    Iran    77.075630   2898.666387 5   579.733277  679.097888
Australia   Australia   23.316017   23.316017   1   23.316017   NaN
Europe  United Kingdom  63.870968   457.929667  6   76.321611   34.647667
Europe  Russian Federation  143.500000  457.929667  6   76.321611   34.647667
Europe  Germany 80.369697   457.929667  6   76.321611   34.647667
Europe  France  63.837349   457.929667  6   76.321611   34.647667
```

How can I write the code properly to make the index `'Continent'` and have the rest of the data grouped by each continent?

Comment: While what @Yike Lu said puts them in order, but I need the index to be listed with each continent in the `'Continent'` index just once as apposed to repeating over and over

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `set_index`.

```py
cont = cont.set_index(['Continent', 'Country']).sort_index()
```

`pandas` collapses index display with multi indexes that are sorted.

`groupby` is more intended for aggregation or looping operations e.g.:

```py
# looping
for continent, gdf in cont.groupby('continent'):
    do_something(gdf)
# aggregation
populations = cont.groupby('continent')['population'].sum()
```

Comment: but I would like each continent to only be listed once in the index as apposed to all the same continent names being grouped together

Comment: Ahh, you might have to use a trick and add a second index. `pandas` only collapses the display for multi-indexes, and not for the last index. I will edit my answer to reflect.